# Where on earth could my startup tasks be?

Tags: files, scripting, autostart

Ok, for context:

I once created a task to run a script whenever I boot my computer up and log in specifically as root.

That was a while ago.

I now want to remove that script from autostarting, but I've forgotten how/where I set it up.

I've already tried looking this up, but I can't find it in:

crontab

/etc/

/etc/xdg/autostart

/usr/share/applications/

/etc/profile.d

or a variety of other locations listed around different autostart tutorials.

It also seems to be absent from the startup list in xfce4-settings manager.

If it's of any use, I'm running xfce4 as my Desk-Env.

**Can anyone think of locations where I may be able to find that damn script?**

Comment: If not in `/etc/crontab`, then maybe a systemd service?

Comment: Not seeing anything relevant in there.

Comment: If the script is invoked after you've logged in as root, would it be in the root account's shell startup files like `/root/.profile`, `/root/.bash_profile`, or `/root/.bashrc`?

Comment: Might sound like a dumb question, but is .bashrc executed when the user logs in, without them having to boot up a terminal?

Comment: Scratch that. That's a yes. I may have found the issue, just gonna test the theory.

Comment: Does it have a ppid != 1?

Comment: Ok, haven't found the issue after all. It's confirmed that it's not an issue with the .bashrc file though.

Comment: Look in "/etc/xdg/autostart" and "~/.config/autostart/" .

Comment: Tried those last night. No luck.